# Add data to data.frame with 0 rows

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Consider this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=3:4)
```

I can add a new column and assign values to it like this:

```
df$c <- 5
```

But if I subset this, so its an empty data.frame and try to assign anything to it, it will return an error:

```
df2 <- subset(df, a==3)
df2$d <- 10
```

> Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "d", value = 10) : 
>     replacement has 1 row, data has 0

This will stop loops, so my question is if there are other ways to assign values to a column in a dataframe that does not return errors when the dataframe is empty?

Comment: You can create a function to check the nrow of dataset before doing assignment i.e. `f1 <- function(dat, cname){dat2 <- dat[dat[[cname]]==3,]; if(nrow(df2)>0) {dat2$d <- 10;dat2} else dat2}`

Comment: That works, but its a bit much to write (i have a long script). There is no "smarter" way to assign values to a column?

Comment: If you use the package `dplyr`, you can add a column with `df2 %>% mutate(d=10)` and it won't crash if there is no row... does it help? So it could be a 1-liner like `df2 <- df %>% filter(a==3) %>% mutate(d=10)`

Comment: You can use `merge(df2, data.frame(d = 10))` instead, that won't fail, but it will mess up the column name..

Comment: If you make the assignment inside `tryCatch` it will not modify df2 and not cause your code to terminate `tryCatch(df2$d <- 10, error = identity)` I think the right answer depends on what you want your desired outcome to be?

Comment: There are lot of splendid answers here but I wonder why one  would want to create a data.frame with one row where only column `d` has a defined value and columns `a`, `b`, `c` are undefined?

Comment: Maybe `if(nrow(df2) == 0){df2$d <- integer(0)} else {df2$d <- 10}`

Comment: @UweBlock      Sometimes my script returns an empty data.frame and sometimes not. The problem is that when the data.frame is empty (and thats okay), it will break my loop.

Comment: @konvas        The output should be an empty an empty data.frame, so your answer actually solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intent of the OP is to create an empty data.frame with an  additional column you may try:

```
df2$d <- integer(0)
df2
#[1] a b c d
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

However, this could have been done in the initial call to `data.frame` as well:

```
data.frame(a = integer(0), b = integer(0), c = integer(0), d = integer(0))
#[1] a b c d
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in one line with `dplyr` by subsetting the data.frame with `filter` and then adding a new column with `mutate`. It won't crash whether your subsetting operation (`filter` here) results in an empty data.frame or not:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=3:4)
df2 <- df %>% filter(a==3) %>% mutate(d=10)
# [1] a b d
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```